# Educational - understanding variable performance of recursive functions with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, function, rcpp, fibonacci

The problem is not of practical nature and I'm only looking for a sound explanation of the observed occurence. I'm reading *[Seamless R and C++ Integration with Rcpp (Use R!)](http://www.worldcat.org/title/seamless-r-and-c-integration-with-rcpp/oclc/848789357)* by Dirk Eddelbuettel. Following the introduction, I'm looking at two simple "Fibonacci functions".

In RStudio I have a cpp file of the following structure

## fib_fun.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int fibonacci(const int x) {
    if (x < 2)
        return x;
    else
        return (fibonacci(x -1)) + fibonacci(x-2);
}

/*** R
# Call the fib function defined in R
fibonacci(10)
*/
```

I also have an inline implementation of the same function:

## inline_fib.R

```
# Inline fib implementation
incltxt <- "int fibonacci(const int x) {
            if (x == 0) return(0);
            if (x == 1) return(1);
            return fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2);
            }"

# Inline call
require(inline)
fibRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(xs = "int"), plugin = "Rcpp",
                       includes = incltxt,
                       body = "int x = Rcpp::as<int>(xs);
                               return Rcpp::wrap(fibonacci(x));")
```

When I benchmark the functions I get the following results:

> ```
> > microbenchmark(fibonacci(10), fibRcpp(10), times = 10)
> Unit: microseconds
>           expr   min    lq   mean median    uq    max neval
>  fibonacci(10) 3.121 3.198 5.5192  3.447 3.886 23.491    10
>    fibRcpp(10) 1.176 1.398 3.9520  1.558 1.709 25.721    10
> ```

## Questions

1. I would like to understand why there is a significant difference in performance between the two functions?
2. With respect to the practicalities surrounding the use of Rcpp, what generally considered to be a good practice? In my naivety, my first hunch would be to write a function and source it via `sourceCpp` but this solutions appears to be much slower.

---

## Benchmarking code

```
require(microbenchmark); require(Rcpp); require(inline)
sourceCpp("fib_fun.cpp"); source("inline_fib.R")
microbenchmark(fibonacci(10), fibRcpp(10), times = 10)
```

---

## Comment replies

I tried the functions with the `unsigned int` instead of the `int`, results:

```
Unit: microseconds
          expr   min    lq   mean median    uq    max neval
 fibonacci(10) 2.908 2.992 5.0369  3.267 3.598 20.291    10
   fibRcpp(10) 1.201 1.263 6.3523  1.424 1.639 50.536    10
```

Comment: If I use `if (x < 2)` rather than             `if (x == 0) return(0);
            if (x == 1) return(1);` The difference in runtime disappears

Comment: @jeremycg thanks very much for showing the interest. So, if I understand correctly, in terms of the performance there is no difference between the in-line and the `sourceCpp` approach.

Comment: what happens if you use `unsigned int x` instead of `int x`. Otherwise I dont see how `if (x < 2)` could be different from `if (x==0).....`

Comment: I just did a C version and it is identical to the `fibRcpp` one, also about twice as fast, but notice that if you increase x to like 20, the difference is much smaller

Comment: My guess -- it's the difference between performing two comparisons, instead of just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All good comments above.

The function is *way too lightweight at `x=10`* and you need to call *way more often* than `times=10` to find anything meaningful.  You are measuring noise.

As for style, most of us prefer `fibonacci()` via Rcpp Attributes...